# Compare a fews ways write JS html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 line for the same consequence

1. `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`
2. `button.onclick=function(){alert('This is my test')};`
3. `button.addEventListener("click", fuction(){alert('This is my test')});`

Could you tell me the way is the best.

Answer (score 5):

**I recommend method 3.**

If you use the first method, one drawback is harder maintenance. If you were to change the function name, then you would need to change it within *multiple* files - the cause of many bugs.

Assuming that you're running your JavaScript *after* the DOM has loaded, I would (personally) define the function, then attach it to the button like so:

```
function buttonListener(event) 
// ...
button.addEventListener('click', buttonListener);
```

This way, your JavaScript stays in one file.

However, if you are executing as fast as possible (no DOM) or were coding in `<script>` tags within a relatively small markup file, then I see no issue with method one.

**Try to avoid method 2** if you can - assigning a property to an anonymous function is slightly harder to read (and is somewhat implicit).

Comment: `button.onclick = buttonListener` would work, so your argument against method 2 is invalid; however, method 3 is as you said the best and should be used